# How to easily create a single-page Web Application?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the easiest way to make a one-page web application, where there will be two input text, in which the variables a, b are entered and one button for accessing the python script to display the image at the received URL

```
def get_pic(a,b):
    *magic*
    return *pic url*
```

I've tried Django, but since I'm a beginner, I didn't understand how to assign a python function call to a button. Maybe there are ways as simple as possible and without unnecessary troubles, I need an elementary interface as in the attached picture

[image]

---

P.S. Before that, I was engaged in creating desktop applications in PyQt and it was much easier there, you just drag-n-drop the necessary buttons, text blocks in the editor and then bind functions to them in Python, but with web applications, as I understand it, it will not work

Comment: does button has to do anything with inputs? If yes then a, b along with button makes a form and on click submits the form. You can access submitted value and do anything with it. Otherwise, you can make an anchor tag (that looks like a button) `<a href="your image"></a>` to your image URL.

Comment: @ItsMilann thx for comment. when i enter a and b text inputs i want to press the button, then python script takes this a, b end return pic url for page

Comment: Can you clarify what a and b have to do with the image?

Comment: @ItsMilann the 'getpick' function takes a,b variables which is keys for the database, and from database function get 'url' field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need simple example how to just pickup values from 2 inputs, and send them down the wire here you go..

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button') ;
var in1 = document.querySelector('#nr1') ;
var in2 = document.querySelector('#nr2') ;
var img = document.querySelector('img') ;
// event on button click
btn.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  // bails. ..todo, security ?..?
  if( !parseInt(in1.value) || !parseInt(in2.value) ) return;
  // take values from input1 and input2 and replace attribute, browser will do ajax for you and render it
  img.setAttribute( 'src', "https://placehold.it/" + in1.value + "x" + in2.value )
});
```

```css
.img, .frm{
  float: left; 
  width: 49%;
  padding-left: 1%
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M9QDwADhgGAWjR9awAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
</div>

<div class="frm">
  <input id="nr1"> <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <input id="nr2"> <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <button>Render</button>
</div>
```

This example will pick integers in two fields and send them to free backend service that will return image.

Your have to replace `https://placehold.it/` with your backend service url, and send args like url parameters as I did for example. Your service needs to return url of the image or mine type `image/png` etc.., it's scripts responsibility to handle security, edge cases, fallback image, etc..

Comment: thanks for the answer, my backend conventionally consists of one backend.py file in which there is the necessary def function, how in your case, I can directly call it, send data from text fields to it and get the return url
// P.S. I'm sorry, but how to get the image in your snippet, what needs to be entered into the text inputs?

Comment: I'm not into python, so please do research how to run function in .py to collect GET parameters (I think that you don't need POST for your use case). Did you tested `snippet` that I send you and see the code?